# Check if a list member is the same inside another list

Tags: python, json, list, for-loop

I have opened a .js database with json library and i have a array of str().
Inside this .js database there is a lot of nested attributes, in variable number, for example:

```
list['indiana']['jones']['degrees']
```

have maybe 2 str() variables and

```
list['albert']['einstein']['degrees']
```

maybe 10 str() variables.

This is the code:

```
import json
json_file = open('database.js')
data = json.load(json_file)
```

...

```
name_biome = ['hills', 'forests']
usable_monsters = []

for k in range(0,len(biome_name),1):
   for bio in mob['features']['environment']:
       if name_biome[k] in bio:
          if float(mob["combatInfo"]["cr"]) < gz2:
             usable_monsters.append(mob)
```

I dont know why i cannot enter inside the if name_biome... the list is quite big (3k mobs circa).
And i tried to find a specific mob entering the right conditions but nothing happend and usable_monsters is still empty.

(all the variables are fine, i have something like 300 lines of code)
(name_biome is a list of str())

Comment: you are trying to index by k and you have not defined k.

Comment: So, what is `name_biome` and what is `k`?

Comment: all the variables are fine, i didnt post the whole code

Comment: I noticed, but we need *relevant* code.

Comment: You're right, sorry i forgot to add the first for loop

Comment: how about ```mob['features']['environment']``` the result is a List or not ?

Comment: yes i want to check if any word inside name_biomes is inside mob['features']['environment'] wich is another list